# Binding without using "Get.to()" for GetX in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I want to bind a controller to `view 1` but I don't want to go to that `view 1` via using `Get.to(Page());`.
Instead I want to use `view 1` directly inside `view 2` by creating an object.

Simplified code (BTW I'm using Veiw1Controller variables inside View1 itself)

```
class Veiw2 extends GetView<Veiw2Controller>{
     return View1();
}
```

When I'm doing the above code, it throws an error saying

> "View1Controller" not found. You need to call
> "Get.put(View1Controller())" or
> "Get.lazyPut(()=>View1Controller())"

I did call `Get.put(...)` in the binding but I think since we are not calling `Get.to()`therefore GetX does not realize when we are using that view and it does not bind the dependencies
Here is what I've done

```
class View1 extends Bindings {
  @override
  void dependencies() {
    Get.put<View1Controller>(
      View1Controller(),
    );
  }
}
```

What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well, the `Bindings` API was made to work together with the `Getx` navigation features, without actually `Get.to()`, `Get.toNamed()`..., you should not expect the automatic dependency injection of `Getx`.

However, you still could inject those dependencies manually: like this:

```
class BindingsOne extends Bindings {
  @override
  void dependencies() {
    Get.put<View1Controller>(
      View1Controller(),
    );
  }
}
```

Now when you want to get a `Widget`:

```
Widget getViewWidget() {
  BindingsOne().dependencies(); // this will inject all your dependencies from the bindings.
  return YourWidget();
}
```

you could also inject them before you use `Navigator` routing features.

```
 // ...
  BindingsOne().dependencies(); // this will inject all your dependencies from the bindings.
  Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => YourWidget()));
}
```